# Guardar valor en funcion base_datos python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenas noches/dias comunidad, tengo un problema con este codigo, he probado varias cosas pero no consigo que datos agregados a las listas se guarden en todas las funciones, al tratar de registrar la asistencia del nuevo dni.

ejemplo, quiero agregar el nombre de "juanito Perez" con dni 75513656, al momento

-Se agrega exitosamente:
[image: Se agrega exitosamente el nuevo registro]
-Luego quiero marca la asistencia con ese dni agregado:
[image: Luego quiero marcar la asistencia con el nuevo dni agregado]

Codigo Fuente:

https://repl.it/@DiegoBejar/Proyecto-Asistencia

Comment: Hola Diego, debes siempre agregar el código a la pregunta, para formatearlo basta con que lo peques, lo selecciones y pulses `Ctrl` + `k` o el botón `{}` del editor. Si agregas el código en un enlace externo se dificulta la lectura del mismo, no puede ser indizado para búsquedas futuras y en un futuro puede no estar accesible el enlace, quedando la pregunta sin utilidad ni contexto.

Comment: Aparte de esto, dos cosas: primero en tu ejemplo ingresas 0 como dni y no el dni agregado (22222222) y 0 no está en la lista... Segundo, hardcodeas la longitud de la lista en `for i in range(5):`, si ingresas nuevos elementos no serán recorridos. Por cierto recorres la lista tres veces cunado iterando solo una vez puedes hacerlo sin problemas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, sevilla ahora lo modifico, ya di con la solucion, era en el for de control tiempo tenia que hacer len a la Nombre [1] y eso que ya me habia topado con ese error, pero bueno somos humanos y aprendemos de los errores, muchas gracias. Codigo modificado

Comment: No puedo pegar el codigo porque es extenso, pero ya lo modifique en el repositorio, y ahora ya me da como lo deseo, gracias nuevamente!